# Switching from pushpool?

Tags: litecoin, server, pushpool

I have a question.
Right no I'm running litecoind + pushpoold + mmcFE (as the front-end), it's a smal sized pool with peaks at around 3000kh/s so far, but we're growing rapidly.

However, some users are getting a LOT of invalid/stale shares. People have been saying their miner can stop for a while, and start subimitting only stales for a couple of minutes, then it goes back to submitting valid ones. Me myself only gets around 10% which seems fair while using getwork.

**Now to the question:**
Is it difficult to switch from pushpoold to say... poolserverJ? I heard it's preferred since it uses GBT (getblocktemplate). This would decrease the amount of work our server does, whilst eliminating invalid shares.

1. Are the shares saved if we switch back-end? (We haven't found a block yet, we're up to a total of about 200k shares so far)
2. Will our users notice any difference on their end?
3. Is poolserverJ compatible with mmcFE for litecoin?

Some help would be awesome!